# GeoServer namespace URI causing invalid WFS transaction requests

Tags: qgis, postgis, geoserver, wfs-t

Is there any naming conventions with GeoServer's namespace URI/settings that need to be changed to allow their proper use?

I have a WFS-T that is being edited in QGIS - after a lot of issues getting 'Empty Response' I found that if I changed my workspace's URI to http://www.opengis.net/wfs then the transaction would be successful. Alternatively if I removed the xsi:schemaLocation= from the request then it is also successful.

The issue is that I can only have one workspace with that URI. If I alter it in anyway the transaction will get an empty response. Any ideas on how to get around this so I can have multiple workspaces?

Answer (score 2):

Any valid URI should be working, if it's not, it might be a client issue. I know we do a lot of WFS-T with URIs setup as `<company's site>/<projectName>` (e.g, http://my.company.com/myproject) from OpenLayers with no issues, but don't have direct experience doing it with QGis.

Comment: Yeh, that's how I thought it should be, but if I do mysite/workspace the transaction fails. I know it's an issue with the xsi:schemaLocation tag but have no way to modify the request prior to it being sent.